# Food that feels a bit rough (though it was meant to be smooth)

Tags: word-request, spoken-english

What will be a natural way to describe the food that feels a bit **rough though it was meant to be smooth?** (Like something rough, gritty texture....)

Will it be called **"grainy", "gritty"**? I mean it might not feel rough to touch but it feels that way. Is there a specific word to describe that?

---

**Edited: Corrected the mistake. (Tastes---> Feels)**

Comment: *Coarse, chunky, lumpy, grainy,...*

Comment: @FumbleFingers , can "grainy" be used to mean "something that feels gritty in the mouth" as well or only as it feels when it's touched?

Comment: And won't "chunky" sound as if "chunks are added on purpose "?

Comment: No more than ***lumpy*** implies deliberately adding lumps, or ***grainy*** implies adding unwanted grains. But you need to give a more exact definition of what you're after. Are we talking about inadequately mashed potato? Apple pie with tough bits of pith/core in it? Inadequately washed leeks containing bits of sand? And many others, I'm sure, but those come to mind as problems that I've complained about on occasion.

Comment: @FumbleFingers , the problem is that I can't explain it properly. It is about something solid, and it feels like there is something rough (like grit) in the food. (So should it be "gritty"? And does "grainy" imply that the food feels "gritty", i.e. does it imply that "gritty", unwanted rough texture when it is put into mouth?

Comment: There's a difference between ***gritty*** (usually, *really* hard particle, such as grains of sand) and for example ***stringy / fibrous*** (some vegetables harvested too late, such as runner beans or celery, contain "unchewable" cellulose fibres that often aren't broken down even by prolonged cooking). Your comment still doesn't tell me exactly what you're getting at. Can you give an example? (Ideally, something that might be eaten in the UK, so I'll recognise it! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers     Um... what I had in mind was "Tamarind". (Is it eaten in the UK?) It was "gritty", as if it had sand.                               And "sprouts", they had something "hard",  that was kind of "gritty"..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit hard to understand what you mean by "it might not feel rough to touch but it tastes that way." Are you really referring to a taste, as opposed to a subtle tactile sensation? Or do you mean it wouldn't feel rough if you touched it with your fingers, but it feels rough to the more sensitive tissues in the mouth? If the latter, you can say it "has a gritty mouthfeel."

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mouthfeel

Comment: No... "I made a mistake". It "feels that way in the mouth ".

Comment: "Has a gritty mouthfeel" should work well, then.

Comment: And what comes to your mind when you listen to "grainy"? Does it have the same meaning as "gritty"?

Comment: "Gritty" suggests particles that are smaller and harder than those I imagine when I hear "grainy." (Literally, "grit" refers to fine sand particles.) "Grain" has a wider range of uses, but generally refers to particles or pieces that aren't that hard. (For example, meat that is undercooked and a bit stringy might be described as "grainy.")

Comment: So it can't be used in my context, right?

Comment: I think "gritty" is just right for that unwanted texture that is sometimes present in tamarind.

Answer (score 3):

Take your pick - you have given a few valid example already (though your use of 'taste' in this context is unusual; you are talking about the texture of the food, how 'it feels in the mouth' rather than the way it tastes.)

Which precise word to use will depend on the speaker and their culture, the expectation with regard to the food (are we talking about soup, or a sauce, or ... ?)

A chef might well use the term 'rustic' as a description for food that is less 'consistent' than might have been expected, but more for visual appearance than for texture.

Comment: Won't "grainy" be used to mean "something that is rough to touch"? Or can it be used to mean something that "feels gritty in the mouth" as well?

Comment: And what will be more likely to be used: "gritty" or "grainy"?

Comment: Both 'gritty' and 'grainy' would work, depending on the circumstances - 'gritty' is perhaps more extreme than 'grainy'. Same with 'bitty', 'lumpy' and a million other words - they each have slightly different connotations.